# How do I upload an image to firebase storage using firebase admin sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm using Next.js here. I need to upload an image to my firebase storage. But it gives me a massive amount of errors. Okay, it gives me 1 error.

Init firebase admin sdk

```js
// firebase.js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import serviceAccount from "./firebase.serviceAccount.json";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
    });
}

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

c
export { firestore, storage };
```

Uploading image

```js
// route.js
import {  storage } from "../../firebase";

const router = async (req, res) => {
    // ...
    // Getting file from api request and so on...
    // ...

    const file = <an instance of File object>;

    const currentTime = Date.now();
    const fileName = file.name;

    const fileTitle = `${currentTime}-${fileName}`;

    const metadata = {
         contentType: file.type
    };

    const task = storage.ref().child(fileTitle).put(file, metadata);


    task.then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);

};

export default router;
```

### error

> Failed to import the Cloud Storage client library for Node.js. Make sure to install the "@google-cloud/storage" npm package. Original error: Error: EIO: i/o error, read

Although I've installed @google-cloud/storage in my package list

Answer (score -4):

1. Add `storageBucket` into your `admin.initializeApp({})`

```js
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  try {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Failed to initialize App: " + e);
  }
}
```

2. Use `admin.storage().bucket()` instead of `admin.storage()`

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import serviceAccount from "./firebase.serviceAccount.json";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
    });
}

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage().bucket();

export { firestore, storage };
```

Comment: You didnt show how to use the storage's bucket to realize an actual upload.